# How to wait till the intent execution is completed in android

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I am calling an app from the other app programatically as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageString,classApp));
mActivity.startActivity(intent, 2);
```

I wanted to wait till Intent app execution is completed and closed.

I tried using the startActivityForResult(intent,2). But this dosnt seems to be working as it is not calling the onActivityResult in the actual activity class.I  am calling the Intent in the non activity class.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to wait till Intent app execution is completed and closed.

That is not possible. You have no way to know when "app execution is completed and closed", particularly since you are starting up that activity in a new task. For example:

- You start the other activity.
- The user presses RECENTS and returns to your app via the overview screen.
- Now what? The user is not required to do anything to "complete and close" that other app.

You are welcome to use lifecycle methods, like `onStart()`, to determine that you are getting control back, but that does not mean that "app execution is completed and closed".

Comment: Instead of waiting, how do i get the response or result back from the new app,so that i can have other operations of my present app working after the response.

Comment: @AshishPatha: You cannot "get the response or result back" from an arbitrary activity. You cannot "get the response or result back" from any activity launched into a new task. *If* the activity that you are trying to start was designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, use that (without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`), and your result will come into your `onActivityResult()` method. However, since you are trying to start the activity from something other than an activity, `startActivityForResult()` is not an option. In that case, what you want is not possible.

Comment: So there is no other way of getting response when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK?

Comment: @AshishPatha: Correct.

Comment: Then how do i open a app from a background service class and wait till the app closes or gives any response. I mean without using Intent as Intent dont have that capability as per the the above discussion.

Comment: @AshishPatha: That is not possible, as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageString,classApp));
setResult(2,intent);

onActivityResult check this.

if(requestCode == 2){

Log.v(TAG ,"Result is Received");
}


please check log in logcat.
```

Comment: So u wanted me to call the setResult after calling startActivityForResult(intent,2) this?